# How do I redirect back to the home page after authentication

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty, lua-resty-openidc

I am trying to configure `lua-resty-openidc` on an NGINX server. How can I redirect back to the Home page once the user is authenticated? When the user is authenticated the callback url is getting the code, session_state and other parameters from the server. This is causing an issue with loading once the user is authenticated.
The url that the user comes back to is something like `http://xyz.abc.com:8080/secured?code=32edkew2kjjjdf`

https://github.com/pingidentity/lua-resty-openidc

My Configuration looks like below. I wanted to take the user back to `http://xyz.abc.com:8080`. What should be the redirect_uri?

```
 local opts = {
             -- the full redirect URI must be protected by this script and becomes:
             -- ngx.var.scheme.."://"..ngx.var.http_host..opts.redirect_uri_path
             redirect_uri_path = "/secured", 
             discovery = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
             client_id = "<client_id",
             client_secret = "<client_secret"
             --authorization_params = { hd="pingidentity.com" },
             --scope = "openid email profile",
             --iat_slack = 600,
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lua-resty-openidc` itself handles the redirect back to the original page that you were trying to access. You don't need to do anything specific for that, it will figure out the that URL when the authentication is triggered, see: https://github.com/pingidentity/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua#L539 and store it in the session.

It will intercept the redirect back to the Redirect URI, see: https://github.com/pingidentity/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua#L557 and eventually redirect back to the original URL, see https://github.com/pingidentity/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua#L350

The Redirect URI itself can be any path as long as it doesn't need to serve content as lua-resty-openidc will intercept it and do its own thing. It does need to be registered with the Provider.

Comment: See this issue that I posted https://github.com/pingidentity/lua-resty-openidc/issues/43

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with session variables. When I replaced return 
`ngx.redirect(session.data.original_url) with  return ngx.redirect("/")`  it is working as expected, redirecting to Home page. I suspect there is some issue with Session variables in openidc.lua. Each time I send a new request from a new browser session I suspect it is still considering old values. It is working as expected every alternate attempt without the above change.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is defined by the `redirect_uri_path` option. You have put `/secured` in this field, so you get a redirection to `http://xyz.abc.com:8080/secured?...`. It you want a redirection to `/`, you can put `redirect_uri_path = "/"` in your options.

But this might not be a good solution, as your probably want to perform some handling **before** redirecting to the home page. The following part of `nginx.conf` could answer your problem:

```
location "=/secured" {
  access_by_lua_block {
    ... -- perform some handling
    return ngx.redirect "/"
  }
}
```

This `location` block is defined for the `/secured` path. It allows to perform some code before redirecting to the home page (the "/" path).

Answer (score -1):

Try this module - github.com/tarachandverma/nginx-openidc
This module is very easy to configure in xml syntax and provides extensive support for redirects in simple xml configuration which can be updated without ever restarting nginx webserver.